# Controlling UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview

In my IOS app i am using a webview to play audio from my website. My problem is that webview plays automatically when i don't even click on the webview.  It says in the ios docs that mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction is equal to true by default but it still plays.  I have tried even setting mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction to true in my code but that still doesn't solve the problem.  I need to stop it from playing without user action because when the user goes to the next screen the webview automatically plays the audio.  I have looked around on stack overflow and none of the solutions i found seem to help with this problem.

Here is my code:

```
//function to get NSURLrequest
    func configureView() -> NSURLRequest {
        let fileNameDownload: AnyObject = self.detailItem!
        let fileNameURL = (fileNameDownload as NSString)
        let spaces = fileNameURL.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        if (spaces.count > 0) {
            let fileNameURL = fileNameURL.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "%20", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: NSMakeRange(0, fileNameURL.length))
            println(fileNameURL)
            let url = NSURL(string: fileNameURL)
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            return request

            }
        else {
            let url = NSURL(string: fileNameURL)
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            return request
        }

    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        previewWebView.loadRequest(configureView())
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using web view? There are other ways to play online audio where you get more control.

Comment: I was using webview because it provided the easiest way for me to preview the audio and then download the audio if the user decided to.  Is there better ways to do this?